# What causes the automatic prompt for permissions in this example from SignalWire

Tags: javascript, html, permissions

I'm working with this example from SignalWire as a base for my own code: [Singnal Wire vanilla-calling example](https://github.com/signalwire/signalwire-node/tree/master/packages/js/examples/vanilla-calling)

I've noticed that the example will automatically ask for permission to use the microphone and webcam, but my own code will not (I'm working in a much larger code base, so I can't just post what I have). I was wondering what causes this behavior in the example, so I can attempt to recreate it in my environment.  Could someone clarify?

If there is anything I can clarify, let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission request is caused by getUserMedia being invoked, which is a browser method (ie. not part of the SignalWire library). The library calls that while setting up the call, so if you are doing something at the lower level you might need to grab devices separately. It is also worth checking that you simply didn't deny access to devices (or have already accepted). Happy to take a look if you can post at least a snippet.

Comment: We found the cause the other day. There was part of our code that incorrectly referenced a method. It didn't error, but it didn't let our code get to the point where getUserMedia would get called. Once tied up it worked.